# Angular8 - BehaviorSubject rxjs

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, components

**My Provider:**

```
organizationMenuLoaded: Observable<ContentResponse>;
private _organizationMenuLoadedSubject: BehaviorSubject<ContentResponse>;
private _organizationMenu: ContentResponse;

getOrganizationMenu() {
  this._organizationMenuLoadedSubject = <BehaviorSubject<ContentResponse>>new BehaviorSubject(new ContentResponse());
  this.organizationMenuLoaded = this._organizationMenuLoadedSubject.asObservable();

this.commonServices.getOrganizationMenu().pipe(map((response) => {
  var results = response['result'];
  var contentResponse = new ContentResponse();
  contentResponse.Menus = results;
  return contentResponse;
})).subscribe((subscription) => {
  this._organizationMenu = subscription;
  this._organizationMenuLoadedSubject.next(Object.assign({}, this._organizationMenu));
});
```

}

**My Login Componenet**

```
constructor(
  private organizationMenuProvider: OrganizationMenuProvider,
) { }
loginSuccess(){
 this.organizationMenuProvider.getOrganizationMenu()
}
```

**MyCurrentComponent**

```
constructor(
  private organizationMenuProvider: OrganizationMenuProvider,
) { }
getDataList(){
  this.organizationMenuProvider.organizationMenuLoaded.subscribe(
  data => {
   console.log(data);
  });
}
```

When I am using console.log(this.organizationMenuProvider.organizationMenuLoaded) in both Provider and Login component, the value was updated but in MycurrentComponent the value was not updated. It's maintaining old value until we refresh the page.
Can anyone suggest me what i have done wrong. Your answer is more valuable. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you provide the `OrganizationMenuProvider`. Is it `providedIn: 'root'` or you have it in the `providers` array in one of your modules?

Comment: It doesn't look like the `organizationMenuLoaded` property in My Provider is ever set? Looks like MyCurrentComponent is subscribing to a property declared to be of an Observable type but not actually assigned to an Observable that would emit any values.

Comment: @DeborahK oops forgot to add. Code updated.